# PS Command in Solaris

Tags: unix, solaris, solaris-10

PS Command output is truncated in Solaris.  I tried the below command  after g
Googling out.  It doesn't work.   Not sure what needs to be done

```
/usr/ucb/ps awwx
```

Comment: What do you mean "truncated"?  Have you read the [manual](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/816-0210/6m6nb7mie?a=view)?

Comment: "It doesn't work" doesn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solaris 10 and later no longer make `/usr/ucb/ps` setuid-root by default, and you need root privileges to poke into the address space of other users processes to get the full set of arguments.

Run it as root or the process owner to see more than 80 characters of the command line.

On Solaris 11, if you use options without a dash (like `/usr/bin/ps auxwww`) they will be treated as UCB style options, and the output will show extra long lines, even when you are NOT running as root.  This is not well publicized.

For further reference:

- [comp.unix.solaris: s10: /usr/ucb/ps output truncated after 79 (80)char when used by nonpriv user ?](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.unix.solaris/browse_thread/thread/26eddd3085e8d2a9/df2358bb57d0ac39)
- [comp.unix.solaris: /usr/ucb/ps auxwww - output truncated for non-root users on Sol10.](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.unix.solaris/browse_thread/thread/915a13275400c88a/a026df6577f91d22#a026df6577f91d22)
- [unix.stackexchange.com: How can I get a full process list in solaris, without truncated lines?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3934/how-can-i-get-a-full-process-list-in-solaris-without-truncated-lines)

**Update**: As of Solaris 11.3 SRU 5.6 (released Feb. 2016), the 80 character limit is removed completely from `ps` - see [Solaris 11.3 SRU 5.6: updates in ps(1) and /proc/<pid>/{cmdline,environ,execname}](https://blogs.oracle.com/casper/entry/solaris_11_3_sru_5).